# What do you call the protrusion that slides into a socket to retain it in place?

Tags: single-word-requests

In many objects in daily life, for example a remote control battery cover, there's usually a protrusion that slides into a socket to retain the object.

[image]

What do you call this protrusion?

A word used in mechanical engineering would be best.

Comment: It's not particularly clear from your sample picture where the protrusion you're referring to is.

Comment: What would you use such a thing for, besides holding batteries in place? I haven't seen those used for other purposes.

Comment: Here are some examples of what you might mean, which might help you clarify your question:  Does it involve the grooves or channels along which the insert slides, allowing motion back and forth parallel to those grooves but preventing any other motions? Does it involve the locking or latching that prevents sliding along the grooves? Something altogether different?

Comment: Plus, in English we ask, “What do you call…” and not, “How do you call…” That’s a common mistake made by a lot of learners.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum Yes, exactly what you said: `involve the grooves or channels along which the insert slides, allowing motion back and forth parallel to those grooves but preventing any other motions`

Comment: 'Battery cover', as you yourself do. I doubt there's a single-word synonym. // Some boxes have sliding lids.

Comment: tongue and groove

Comment: The actual protrusion that fits into a slot would probably be called a *tab* or a *hook* or even a *hooked tab*, and the tab/slot mechanism combined could be considered a *latch*.

Comment: *runner* as in *track and runner*, maybe.

Comment: Sometimes called a "hatch", but I don't see it as a protrusion. A protrusion is something that sticks out (protrudes) permanently, not something which protrudes only when it's moved out of the way. A protrusion which fits into an aperture is a _tenon_ but that protrudes permanently from the component of which it is a part and is hidden only because it is fitted into the _mortice_ which is a hole cut into another component.

Comment: I'm happy to see that @Weather Vane has withdrawn their simplistic answer here. I'm not aware of any reasonable SW answer; 'battery cover' is what I'd use, but it's a two-word term and again over-simplistic for ELU.

Comment: If you want a precise engineering term, rather than an informal term a non-engineer would use, ask in https://engineering.stackexchange.com/ not here.

Comment: As a general term (e.g., it's not always a cover), it could be called a **tab**. A tab (one of its meanings) is a protrusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there's some unusual term specific to the engineering profession, I think "tongue and groove" fits the bill better than anything else I can think of.  The bit that sticks out is the tongue, and the slit it fits into is the groove.

I *don't* think it would apply to a similar structure where there's a ridge along which another part slides (as you might have along the *sides* of a cover such as pictured in OP.)  Tongue and Groove is specific to a particular point on the structure.

Less colorfully, you may simply call it a "tab" and "slot"

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a single name for these.  Names which can be used include

- The term specific for the case you showed is **battery compartment slide(r)**, but there are other more generic terms for other variants implied in your question.
- accessible compartment cover
- battery access slider
- battery flap
- compartment door

Answer (score 0):

If the question is about a small part that flexes to snap into a cutout or recess, thereby locking the cover in place -- not just asking about the cover, then here's an answer:

Besides holding a cover in place, similar parts are on an Ethernet RJ plug and Display Port connector. There's a tiny notch that snaps automatically when you plug in the cable. It is released by pressing down on a tiny lever or button to remove the cable.

I do not have one definitive name. These are possibilities used in various contexts:
Catch
Latch or latching mechanism
Tab
Finger
Hook or hooking tab, latch, finger, etc.